# How to prevent ScrollView from capturing taps outside of it bounds in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Here is my full code you can run:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Rectangle().frame(height: 100)
                ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                    ForEach((0..<1000)) { index in
                        NavigationLink("Click on this line - \(index)", destination: Text("CONGRATS!! ITS \(index)!!!"))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's a simple VStack with 2 views embedded -> A `Rectangle` and a `ScrollView`

The Bug:  Scroll the Scroll view.
If you now Tap the rectangle, the rows of the scrollview gets tapped.

How is this possible when they are separated inside a VStack? And How can I fix this?

Comment: This seems to be a bug with Xcode 12 Beta when building for iOS 14. I don't have this bug when Im using Xcode 11.5 or when building for iOS 13.5 in Xcode 12 Beta, only when Im building for iOS 14 in Xcode 12 Beta.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.
I filed this as a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work around fix
from [@SwiftUILab](https://twitter.com/SwiftUILab)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Rectangle().frame(height: 100)
                ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                    ForEach((0..<1000)) { index in
                        NavigationLink("Click on this line - \(index)", destination: Text("CONGRATS!! ITS \(index)!!!"))
                    }
                }.contentShape(Rectangle())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That indeed solves it. Interesting. Do you remember the post from @SwiftUILab where you found this workaround fix?